# Where to put tests for test utility methods?

Tags: unit-testing, testng

I've been reading *xUnit Patterns: Refactoring Test Code*, a great book by Gerard Meszaros, and decided to have more tested utility methods for my unit tests. As far as I can see, there are three places to put such utilities:

1. If an utility method is used only in a single testcase class, put it right there.
2. If it's used in several testcase classes across a single project, put it into a separate test helper class.
3. If it's used more than in one project, put it into a separate test utility lib.

The question is, if I'm going to have *tested* utilities, where do I put tests for them?

In case (3), no problem. The test utility lib is just a regular project with its own suite of tests.

Case (1) is a bit more complicated: the only logical place is to put the tests into the same testcase class, but how to make sure the "normal" tests are skipped if the utility tests fail? I can introduce dependencies between tests (say, use TestNG's attribute `dependsOnGroups = "utilities"`), but that looks a bit ugly: for example, I need to duplicate that attribute on every test or group them into nested testcase classes that depend on each other.

Case (2) is a real mess. Putting the tests into the helper class looks ugly and may break test discovery if something (Maven, IDE) expects testcase classes to end with `Test` and my helper class doesn't. Putting the tests into a separate `HelperTest` testcase class sounds better, but then I have another dependency problem: if I make some tests depend on that `HelperTest` class, then they will all happily fail if I run just a single test file because during that run those utility tests don't even exist (at least with TestNG).

Am I missing something? Is there an industry-wide tradition how to deal with this? Or should I just forget about dependencies and just look for utility tests in the red list in case of bunch of tests failing all at the same time?

Comment: *how to make sure the "normal" tests are skipped*: just don't. Tests fail, so what. You find the reason why they fail, fix the faulty code, and re-run the tests. I think you're over-thinking this.

Comment: @JBNizet, could be. But I've read many times in articles and books that many tests failing at once is bad because it's hard to tell the reason. I personally never had any problems with it, but it sounds reasonable enough to try. Maybe the idea is nice, but we just don't have the right tools to follow it yet.

Comment: Imagine you have a utility method in your production code, that many of your production classes use. If you introduce a bug in this utility method, many of the tests for these classes should fail. Yet you're not trying to introduce a dependency between the tests of the classes and the tests of the utility method, because the usage of this utility method by the classes is an implementation detail, that your tests should not care about. It shouldn't be any different for a utility method which is part of the test source set.

Comment: @JBNizet, now that makes perfect sense. This should really be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a utility method in your production code, that many of your production classes use.

If you introduce a bug in this utility method, many of the tests for these classes should fail. Yet you're not trying to introduce a dependency between the tests of the classes and the tests of the utility method, because the usage of this utility method by the classes is an implementation detail, that your tests should not care about.

It shouldn't be any different for a utility method which is part of the test source set. Tests should assume that this test utility method works fine. If it doesn't then there shouldn't be a problem finding the root cause of the failing tests, especially if you have a test for this utility method that also fails.